# How can I create a regular expression in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create regular expressions to filter certain text from a text file. What I want to filter has this format:

```
word_*_word.word
```

So for example, I would like the python code every match. Sample results would be:

```
program1_0.0-1_log.build
program2_0.1-3_log.build
```

How can I do this?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+_[^_]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+'
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you want to use a pattern such as `r'\w+_.*_\w+\.\w+'` -- assuming that `*` you have does stand for "zero or more totally arbitrary characters" (if not, then the `.*` part in the middle needs to be changed accordingly).  Once you have the right pattern (depending exactly on what you mean by that `*`;-), you can `re.compile` it to get a regular expression object, and use the `.findall` method of the RE object, with your overall string as an argument, to get a list of all non-overlapping substrings matching this pattern (there are also alternatives such as e.g. `.finditer` if you want to get one such substring at a time, looping over them).

Answer (score 1):

Python's regular expression module is called `re`. You need to import it and use the [provided functions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#module-contents):

```
import re
if re.match(r'\w+_.*_\w+.\w+', "some_text_abc.x"):
   print "yeah."
```

It is useful to prefix the regular expression string with `r`, so that it will be interpreted literally, without special handling for escape characters. Otherwise backslashes will be treated specially by the python interpreter and backslashes that are part of the regular expression need to be escaped.

Comment: This matches "any number of underscores" which seems peculiar (and doesn't satisfy the OP's example).

Comment: @sth, tx -- also, `re.match` only matches at the _start_ of the string (as if the pattern started with an implied `^`, in a sense) so it probably won't get "every match" in the file as the OP asks for.

Comment: Well, my main point was more to point to the `re` module, it's docs and it's basic usage. It seemed to me like this is the basic problem the OP wants to solve first, before caring about the exact regular expression and what exactly should be matched. (I basically just focused on the *in python* part, not the *what regular expression* part)

Answer (score 0):

try with `^\w+_.*_\w+\.\w+$`

Comment: You won't get "every match", as the OP desires, by anchoring the pattern so that it only matches an entire line (if you remembered to specify `re.MULTILINE` -- otherwise, only the entire file, and only if it had no newlines within if you didn't specify `re.DOTALL`;-).

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand why you would need a regex here. 
If the strings you want ends with ".build", you can do this for example

```
s="blah blah program1_0.0-1_log.build blah blah"    
for item in s.split():
    if item.endswith(".build"):
        print item
```

and that's it. If you want to do further checking, then

```
for item in s.split():
    if item.endswith(".build"):
        s = item.split("_")
        if len(s) != 3:
           print "not enough _"
```

Comment: you might prefer to use a regex to find the stuff with 1 line of code, as opposed to your multi-line loops.

Comment: i seldom use regex with Python, unless absolutely necessary. Using Python's internal string methods is faster as well, IMO.